# Pre-populating Form Fields in Web Forms for Marketers

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have just loaded Web forms for Marketers and it works great, but my user asked for a new requirement which is to pre-populate several fields, prior to rendering the form. 
1) is this possible, I would like to believe it is but I am not certain how? 
2) are there are any examples or a resource I could use to do this?

These are simple fields so I am thinking this can't be that difficult. 
I would be very appreciative for any responses I receive on this.
Regards,

Paul T. Rykiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Forms Designer you can add a standard value to a field, but I'm not sure if this is enough. IE. you want to do it programatically.

But in the Forms Designer, load your form and click on a field and the option will be on the top on the left side.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it out. This is more than what Sitecore has offered.